# Halting the code until the user inputs data on dialog prompt

Tags: java, android

I have an app that lets the user type text and export it to a txt file. When the user presses the save button a dialog comes up asking the user how they want to name the file. The user types a name which is taken as a string value, and then it is being concatenated along with ".txt" for the final file name. The problem is that the program saves the file instantly without waiting for the user to input a name, so it will use the previous value of the string, even if it is null. When it is null, the file name will be "null.txt". Next time user attempts to save a file, the app will save the file instantly and use the value previously inputted in the first attempt and it goes on like that.

Save button:

```
saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        openDialog(); //Calls for the dialog pop-up

        exportText = resultText.getText().toString().trim(); //.trim() removes space before and after text
        if (!exportText.isEmpty()) {
            saveToTxtFile(exportText);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SpeechToText.this, "Input field empty...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Method doing the saving:

```
private void saveToTxtFile(String mText) {

    try {
        File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); //path to storage
        File dir = new File(path + "/My App/Text Files/"); //create folders 
        dir.mkdirs();
        String fileName = inputName + ".txt"; 

        File file = new File(dir, fileName);

        //FileWriter class is used to store characters in file
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(mText);
        bw.close();

        Toast.makeText(SpeechToText.this, "Saved successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //if anything goes wrong
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The dialog pop-up method:

```
public void openDialog() {
    View view = (LayoutInflater.from(SpeechToText.this)).inflate(R.layout.user_input, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SpeechToText.this);
    alertBuilder.setView(view);
    final EditText userInput = view.findViewById(R.id.userInput);

    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            inputName = String.valueOf(userInput.getText());
        }
    });
    Dialog dialog = alertBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you call your `saveToTxtFile(String mText)` in the Dialog onClick listener present in the `openDialog()` method after and put it after `inputName = String.valueOf(userInput.getText());` ?

Comment: This wont solve the issue. It still uses the previous String value not the current.

Comment: See my updated answer and see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `saveToTxtFile()` before user can input the file name in the Dialog prompt.

Just call it in the Dialog `onClick` listener after `inputName = String.valueOf(userInput.getText());` with a null check. Also it would be better if you change your file saving method

```
saveToTxtFile(String mText)
```

to

```
saveToTxtFile(String mText, String filename)
```

that way you will be sure what file name is being passed to the this method.

Like this

```
alertBuilder.setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        inputName = String.valueOf(userInput.getText());
        if(inputName != "" && inputName != null)
           saveToTxtFile(exportText,inputName);
        else
           //Toast an error here
    }
});
```

Also in your `saveBtn` click listener call `openDialog()` where you were calling `saveToTxtFile(exportText);` inside the `if (!exportText.isEmpty())` body.

Like this :

```
exportText = resultText.getText().toString().trim(); //.trim() removes space before and after text
    if (!exportText.isEmpty()) {
         openDialog();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(SpeechToText.this, "Input field empty...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

That way it will only ask for the filename if the file content is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but you could try something like this...

You should only call `openDialog` when `saveBtn` is tapped

```
saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openDialog(); //Calls for the dialog pop-up
    }
});
```

Then when add a save button to the dialog and save the data at that point. Adding the `onShowListener` will prevent the dialog from closing until you need it to.

```
public void openDialog() {
View view = (LayoutInflater.from(SpeechToText.this)).inflate(R.layout.user_input, null);

AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SpeechToText.this);
alertBuilder.setView(view);
final EditText userInput = view.findViewById(R.id.userInput);

alertBuilder.setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Ok", null).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
Dialog dialog = alertBuilder.create();
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
   @Override
   public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        Button deleteAllButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        deleteAllButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  inputName = String.valueOf(userInput.getText());
                  exportText = resultText.getText().toString().trim(); //.trim() removes space before and after text
                  if (!exportText.isEmpty()) {
                     saveToTxtFile(exportText);
                     dialog.dismiss();
                  } else {
                     Toast.makeText(SpeechToText.this, "Input field empty...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              }
    });

    Button cancelButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
               dialog.dismiss();
          }
    });

  }
 });
 dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a listener attached to your dialog for eg--

```
        Dialog dialog;

    dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        dialog.show();


    TextView tv_message = (TextView) dialog .findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);

    tv_message.setText(message);

    Button bt_yes = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonYes);
       Button bt_no = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonNo);

    bt_yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //HERE GOES YOUR CODE YOU WANT TO BE EXECUTED
// AFTER THE USER INOUTS ITS NAME AND HIT OK.

 exportText = resultText.getText().toString().trim(); //.trim() removes space before and after text
        if (!exportText.isEmpty()) {
            saveToTxtFile(exportText);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SpeechToText.this, "Input field empty...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        }
    });
    bt_no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```